# SlidingMenu (jfeinstein10) : setMenu doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I'm using SlidingMenu (jfeinstein10) for my android application, but setMenu function raises errors.

My code is here:

```
// configure the SlidingMenu
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);

menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setBehindOffset(100);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
```

What did I wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: What error does it shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling all day, I have found an issue.
The issue was in my layout - R.layout.sliding_menu.
I have used custom TextView with my own font, and I have misspelt font name.

I have found that other users also have same issues, and I hope this may help them.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the activity of the menu with this:

```
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
```

Complete code:

```
// configure the SlidingMenu
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
//this to slide only the content
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
//or this to slide navBar too
//menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setBehindOffset(100);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
```